# Rust-Analyzer VSCode-Plugin with Tauri

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-cargo, tauri, rust-analyzer

When working on a Tauri project in VSCode, I get the following error message from the **rust-analyzer** plugin.

```
rust-analyzer failed to discover workspace
```

I know that the cause of the problem is that I loaded the Tauri project as my workspace in VSCode which does not have a `Cargo.toml` in its project root, but in the Rust-related sub-directory `src-tauri`. Is there a way I can tell the plugin that it should refer to this sub-directory `src-tauri` for the `Cargo.toml`? The workaround is to switch the workspace to `src-tauri` every time I touch the Rust code, which is quite inconvenient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`rust-analyzer.linkedProjects`](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#configuration) setting in VSCode. It takes a list of paths pointing to `Cargo.toml` files.

Try adding this to your `settings.json`:

```
"rust-analyzer.linkedProjects": [
    "src-tauri/Cargo.toml",
],
```